# Speedtouch st780i is blocking ICMP

Tags: ping, icmp

I'm working on a tool in VB to make ping tests, but some speedtouch 780i routers are blocking ICMP.

I try it out myself on a speedtouch router. I telnet and disable the firewall and intrusion detection, but still the ICMP is blocked.

The actual question I have is not how to fix to allow the ICMP running over the Speedtouch router configuration. I'm more interested **how to work around this problem without touching the router**.

I noticed that if I make a ping test over a web application using my browser, everything works fine. If the ping is made over the cmd, it's not working. I'm thinkin it might be a port problem but I'm really not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Most websites are intentionally blocking ICMP to prevent Denial of Service attacks and SQL injection attacks to their sites.